# Get request from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

Hello I want to show the result of this JSON in PHP, I have this:

```
$r = {"person1":{"id":100,"name":"Robert"}}

$obj = json_decode($r);

Name: <?php echo $obj->{'name'};?><br>
```

How can I show it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the `person1` on your object.

```
<?php
$r = '{"person1":{"id":100,"name":"Robert"}}';
$obj = json_decode($r);
echo $obj->person1->name; //"prints" Robert
echo $obj->person1->id; //"prints" 100
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/104265)

Answer (score 0):

use like this, output will be in associative array format

```
$array = json_decode($r,true);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = {"person1":{"id":100,"name":"Robert"}}
$obj = json_decode($r);
var_dump($obj); // this will show you $obj structure
```